# Keycloak Auth screen not shown in Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, keycloak

I am using Keycloak for user management for a mobile app. Everything works as expected on an AVD. However when testing on an actual Android device, the Keycloak authentication screen is not shown.

Anybody any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have further details on what's going on??